# Regex - find html text inside link

Tags: php, regex

Here is my sentence :

```
<p>
    random <b>html content</b> 
    <a 
        href="http://www.google.com" 
        target="_blank" 
        data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=fr&amp;q=http://www.randomsite.com&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1481293002613000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHR0HJfUDpRN_7vq022fQiLzXf0yQ"
    >
        <span class="il">content</span>.n1
    </a> 
    fdfdf<br/>
    dsdsd <a href="dsdsdsds">content n2</a>
```

I'm trying to get all the content inside the link :

```
<span class="il">content</span>.n1
```

and

```
content n2
```

I tried :

```
/<a.*\>{1}(.*)<\/a>/
```

But It seems I cannot "target" the first closing tag ">" which can allow me to target the links content

https://regex101.com/r/coekvw/2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What dont you use the built in PHP class DOMDocument for this? http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: `<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>`

Comment: @Kitson88 > I need to wrap the text link within custom tags and I thought regex was not the worst solution. I you have an example with DOMDocument where I can replace the content, you're welcome.

Comment: @Philipp > Yes, that's great. Thanks :)